# Not able to return JSON data from NodeJS server coded using Typescript

Tags: jquery, express, typescript

My project has NodeJS + Express in the back end that has to return JSON data as a POST response to the front end in JQuery. For some reason the message does not reach the front end - whcih uses JQuery AJAX call. Although I'm not entirely sure where its breaking, because the front end code is supposed to show an alert message whether the call fails or succeeds, but no message is shown.

Server:

```
// <reference path="lib/Main.d.ts" />

import express = require('express');
import http = require('http');
import path = require('path');
import fs = require('fs');

var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var formidable = require('formidable');

var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());

// all environments

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


/**
 * Receives JSON Data
 */

app.post("/data", function (request, response){
    console.log("Body called");
    var x = String(request.body.test);
    console.log(x);
    console.log("Sending response");
    var resp = "Received " + x;
    response.send(JSON.stringify({
        message : resp
    }));
});
```

Client:

```
function start() {
     send({
        test: 123
    },function test(responseData){
            alert(responseData);
        }
    )
}


function send(data : any, success:(String) => void){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/data',
        success: function (responseData) {
            var x = JSON.parse(responseData);
            alert("success");
            success(x.body.message);
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert("failure");
            var e = serverCommunicationFailureError();
            e.displayErrorMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

Console Message:

```
Body called
123
Sending response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains

```
return JSON.parse(responseData);
alert("success");
```

How do you think it can reach the `alert` call if that is after a `return` statement?

Comment: Thanks. That was clearly wrong. Even after, having fixed it, nothing has changed in the output. Do you see any other problems?

Comment: Shouldn't the code in the `success` handler be `success(x.message)`?

Comment: Still not working. Do you see any actual syntactical errors, other than bad coding?

Answer (score 0):

you can use body-parser to parse the JSON data

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express"


const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json(options));

// You can replace these options with the available options
// available options are

// - limit
// - revived
// - inflate
// - strict
// - type
// - verify

// example

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "10mb" }));
```